# Why is this function undefined?

Tags: jquery, scope

I was hoping i was past this... but why is is resize undefined on Button click?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var w = [320, 480];
    var h = [480, 620];

    function resize (input){
        $("scale").width(w[input]);
        $("scale").height(h[input]);
    }

    $.each(w, function(i, val){
        $("<button onclick='resize("+i+")'>"+val+"</button>").appendTo("body");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You should use `.on('click', function(){...})` instead if you're using jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Because inline JavaScript (which you should *not* be using) can only reference global functions.  `resize` is not a global function.

Comment: A quick fix would be to add `window.resize = resize` after your function declaration but I don't suggest doing that.

Answer (score 5):

Because its inside the document.ready function.

You need to have the resize function at the global level for the DOM to see it.

However a better way of doing it would be to use the jQuery "on" function.

Answer (score 0):

`function resize` exists only in the scope of the onReady callback you pass into `document.ready` ... It needs to exist "higher up" / "more globally" for this to work, or do what @blazemonger mentions, bind it directly instead of using the onclick= html attribute